# Why animation play in t pose?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

On the left is the character I use as the main one, with a camera and a Character controller, and on the right is a prefab. They have the same animation settings, Animator Avatar is the same for both.[Left is my main char, right is prefab from asset store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRPCX.png)
Sorry i dont know how to pin gif because she is very large (15 mb).

I tried to turn the prefab into my main character with a camera and a Character Controller. But at some point (maybe after restarting Unity) the same thing happened
`https://gifyu.com/image/Sl2NT`
Gif here